# not able catch exception in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a issue need your help to resolve. I have a text box where user enter url of interest and click on "Go" Below code gets executed(bascially i'm making a ajax call ) I convert the url of interest to absolute path and load to iframe. In some cases in the third party website if it generates error my dom of iframe is spoiled. My iframe context menu is not loaded properly. So thought of adding try catch block to swallow the error.
but as soon as control hits document.getElementById('iframeid') it enters jquery library and exception happens and control goes to $(document).ready(function(){
**instead of catch block...**
***Please help how to catch the error even if error happens in third party website all my dom elements should be loaded properly.***

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"Service/rootURL/post",
        data:input,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            try{
            document.getElementById('iframeid').src="htmls/ThirdPartyWebSiteStore/test.html";
            }catch(e){
                console.log("Error Occured");
            }
            showInformationMessage('#StepsInfoDivCapture',20000);
            return true;
        },
```

Comment: Is it a cross domain iframe?

Comment: Check the headers in your network inspector.

Comment: @wolff : it is no longer cross domain because I download the third party webpage and convert relative address to absolute address. And load it from local

Comment: @AdrianPreuss did you mean network tab in chrome development tool

Comment: sure. Check out, that response headers are coming in

Comment: no errors reported at response header.. but in console I get it. I know in one of the case third party website following code is there window.location.href.split('.com')[1]; pageNameSplitValue.indexOf('HaveAccountView') == -1 which looks for .com. But as I'm running locally above code get localhost and no .com element is present in window.location hence indexof of undefined. which in turn generate error... which is not caught in catch block. Above stated is one of the case but I want a generic solution.